# search performance in python pandas vs. numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, search, numpy, pandas

I am trying to search a string in a pandas column. I have read that it should be fastest to sort the column first and search the string using searchsorted on the values. I figured out that this is slower than searching brute force (array == string) on a same numpy array. To see why, I have performed the following tests:

```
import timeit

setup4 = '''  
import numpy as np, string, random 

d =     np.array([
            u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16))
             for _ in range(20000)
             ],dtype=np.object)
'''



setup5 = '''  
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, string, random 

header = [
                    u'A',
                    u'B',
                    u'C',
                    u'D',
                    u'E',
                    u'F',
                    u'G',
                    u'H',
                    u'I',
                    u'J',
                    u'K',
                    u'L',
                    u'M',
                    u'N'
                    ]


data =     [[pd.to_datetime('20140505'),
                u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16)),
                u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16)),
                u'sfgweorfjdfl',
                u'dsiofqjwel;dmfv',
                u'e3ruiwefjvgoiubg',
                u'3124oirjrg;klhbas',
                u';3rhfgfbnvsad3r',
                pd.to_datetime('20140505'),
                u'1234irtjurgbfas',
                u'12;rhfd;hb;oasere',
                u'124urgfdnv.,sadfg',
                u'1rfnhsdjk.dhafgsrdew',
                u'safeklrjh2nerfgsd.'
                ] for _ in range(20000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=header)
df_sorted = df.sort(['B','C'])
e = df_sorted['B'].values
'''

setup6 = '''  
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, string, random 

header = [
                    u'A',
                    u'B',
                    u'C',
                    u'D',
                    u'E',
                    u'F',
                    u'G',
                    u'H',
                    u'I',
                    u'J',
                    u'K',
                    u'L',
                    u'M',
                    u'N'
                    ]


data =     [[pd.to_datetime('20140505'),
                u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16)),
                u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16)),
                u'sfgweorfjdfl',
                u'dsiofqjwel;dmfv',
                u'e3ruiwefjvgoiubg',
                u'3124oirjrg;klhbas',
                u';3rhfgfbnvsad3r',
                pd.to_datetime('20140505'),
                u'1234irtjurgbfas',
                u'12;rhfd;hb;oasere',
                u'124urgfdnv.,sadfg',
                u'1rfnhsdjk.dhafgsrdew',
                u'safeklrjh2nerfgsd.'
                ] for _ in range(20000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=header)
f = df['B'].values
'''

print(timeit.timeit("index = d == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'", setup=setup4,number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit("index = e == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'", setup=setup5,number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit("index = f == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'", setup=setup6,number=1000))
```

With the following result:

```
print(timeit.timeit("index = d == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'", setup=setup4,number=1000))
0.808505267014

print(timeit.timeit("index = e == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'", setup=setup5,number=1000))

3.06733738226

print(timeit.timeit("index = f == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'", setup=setup6,number=1000))
1.64207848896
```

My question here: Why is the performance on the pure numpy array so much better? And how could I achieve the same performance using the data extracted from the pandas table?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe pandas although uses numpy arrays underneath it does more dtype checking and aligning so is slower: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834075/pandas-much-slower-than-numpy

Comment: Okay, but in all 3 cases, I am operating on numpy arrays. The only difference is that for the first case, the array is natively constructed as a numpy array, whereas in the later two cases, the arrays are extracted from pandas data frames using "values".

Comment: Your second setup is sorting and returning a copy of the dataframe, the third setup doesn't do this but there appears to be some overhead with constructing the dataframe and then returning the data as a numpy array. I don't know the full inner workings of pandas to explain more but it would be useful to time just the creation of the dataframe so you can get an idea of the cost of sorting and accessing the data as a numpy array via `.values`

Comment: Everything in `setup` is not counted in the timer of `timeit`

Comment: Ah OK, I misunderstood what your timeit was profiling exactly, yes that is odd there should not be a significant difference between them apart from the sorted dataframe versus unsorted

Comment: Actually I just ran your code and I get similar timings for all three 536, 565 and 538 us respectively

Comment: What version pandas and numpy are you using? I am running 0.14.0 pandas and numpy 1.8.1

Comment: @user3582129 sorting is not relevant here as you are comparing versus EVERY element. Further you are comparing numpy arrays directly (and not pandas structures), ``.values`` returns the numpy array

Comment: @Jeff Yes, exactly, that's why I am wondering why there is a difference in performance. It looks to me that the operation should be identical in all 3 cases

Comment: @EdChum I am using numpy 1.8.1 and pandas 0.14.0

Comment: Also, I just figured out that using `.copy(order='C')` on the values does indeed give identical results. It seems to me that the data in pandas is somehow unfavorably distributed in memory, could that be?

Comment: I'll post how I tested this so you can critique whether what I did was comparable

Comment: @user3582129 I am puzzled why these tiny differences actually matter in reality? you are always subject to memory layout differences.

Comment: @Jeff The difference is a factor 4 in the worst case. And the test has a loop of 1,000 iterations, whereas in reality, I have to evaluate it 1,000,000 times.

Comment: why would you loop doing this type of indexing? You are not using the power of pandas here, just use ``.isin``, and or/join, see this for benchmarks: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7398

Comment: I have data set (A) and I have to find for each entry in A all rows in B with the same data in the first column. Then I perform some calculation using this data from B and insert the result back to A. I think I have to search for A[i,1] in B[1], and `.isin` is not very fast in searching single items (2 seconds in the above case).

Answer (score 0):

Every string in DataFrame is an object, what you get from `df['B'].values` is an object array. But when you create a string array by `np.array()`, it returns an array that every string use the same byte count.

Here is an example, `a` is an array with `S10` dtype, `b` is an array with object dtype.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import string
words = ["".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(10)) for _ in range(10000)]
a = np.array(words)
b = a.astype("O")
%timeit a == "123"
%timeit b == "123"
```

the output:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 122 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 164 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yes, I have realized that. Therefore, the numpy array is of `dtype=np.object`. Also it would not explain the difference between the sorted and the unsorted array from pandas (cases 2 and 3).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in IPython and got pretty much the same performance for all variants apart from the unsorted dataframe:

```
In [85]:

import numpy as np, string, random 

d =     np.array([
            u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16))
             for _ in range(20000)
             ],dtype=np.object)

header = [
                    u'A',
                    u'B',
                    u'C',
                    u'D',
                    u'E',
                    u'F',
                    u'G',
                    u'H',
                    u'I',
                    u'J',
                    u'K',
                    u'L',
                    u'M',
                    u'N'
                    ]


data =     [[pd.to_datetime('20140505'),
                u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16)),
                u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16)),
                u'sfgweorfjdfl',
                u'dsiofqjwel;dmfv',
                u'e3ruiwefjvgoiubg',
                u'3124oirjrg;klhbas',
                u';3rhfgfbnvsad3r',
                pd.to_datetime('20140505'),
                u'1234irtjurgbfas',
                u'12;rhfd;hb;oasere',
                u'124urgfdnv.,sadfg',
                u'1rfnhsdjk.dhafgsrdew',
                u'safeklrjh2nerfgsd.'
                ] for _ in range(20000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=header)
df_sorted = df.sort(['B','C'])
e = df_sorted['B'].values
f = df['B'].values
%timeit index = d == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'
%timeit index = e == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'
%timeit index = f == u'ASDASD123ASADKHX'
1000 loops, best of 3: 536 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 568 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 538 µs per loop
```

Comment: That's interesting. What happens if you use the code exactly as printed above? I have added the `import timeit`, so it should now be a self-consistent python file.

Comment: I ran your code and got the following: `2.11338382930262
1.2496556612022687
0.6459569358412409` which is opposite to what you observed, I then ran it again and got `0.5910921373142628
1.7401513672084548
0.5598322421719786` if you rerun your code do you get random results?

Comment: Just ran it again and got `0.5474049547920004
0.6093832207843661
0.5601899379689712`, doesn't seem to be any mystery here to me

Comment: No, it is actually very consistent. The numbers vary slightly, but not too much.

Comment: I have now used my Linux PC at home to repeat the test (I have copied the code from here) and the result is the same: 1.6, 5.5, and 3.2 seconds. I am wondering what the difference between your test and mine is.

Comment: @user3582129 I can't really say now I'm running winpython python 3.3 64-bit but the key bits are pandas 0.14 and numpy 1.8.1 I really can't explain why there is a difference between our results

Comment: Maybe the difference is that I am using python 2.7?

Comment: @user3582129 maybe try 3.3 and see if it is better, otherwise I have no other thoughts to explain the difference

Comment: @user3582129 it's a complete mystery to me, sorry I couldn't shed any light on this