# Fastest way to changes rows in a Series by slicing in pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a large Series datastructure in pandas and I need to edit certain values using slicing. I start with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

vec = np.random.randn(1e7)
sr  = pd.Series(vec)
idx = (np.random.rand(10000)*1000).astype(int)
```

Replacing elements in vec using idx is much faster

```
timeit vec[idx] = 1.2
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.5 µs per loop
```

than for the pandas structure

```
timeit sr[idx] = 1.2
1 loops, best of 3: 391 µs per loop

timeit sr.iloc[idx] = 1.2
1000 loops, best of 3: 201 µs per loop
```

Is there any way to get the same performance with pandas as with numpy for this specific operation?

Comment: No, pandas is performing a lot of additional work which numpy is not, see http://penandpants.com/2014/09/05/performance-of-pandas-series-vs-numpy-arrays/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834075/pandas-much-slower-than-numpy so pandas it performing a lot more checking under the hood than numpy

Comment: This makes sense! Many thanks for the references - I've been looking for comparisons and discussions about the relative performance between pandas and numpy but it's surprisingly hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sr.values[idx] = 1.2` has performance comparable to `vec[idx] = 1.2`:

```
In [101]: %timeit vec[idx] = 1.2
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.8 µs per loop

In [102]: %timeit sr.values[idx] = 1.2
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: strangely `sr.values[idx]` takes 42.9us against `vec[idx] = 1.2` taking 59.4us

Comment: Ah apologies, I wasn't assigning that's why it was noticeably faster it's now 62.8us v 59.6us

Comment: That makes sense since sr.values is just a view of the underlying ndarray object. Seems like this is the best way to go if I want to use a pandas data structure. Thanks!